# How do I move a source folder or file to different folder after a get file is used but later in the flow?

Tags: apache-nifi

I'm trying to figure out a way to move the source folder or file(s) we receive to a 'pending_process' folder.

The getFile just gets the file and has an option to delete the source or leave it.

*What I need to do is the following*

1. Detect when a file arrives
2. Move that source file that arrived to a folder 'pending_process'
3. Detect when a file arrives in the folder 'pending_process'
4. GetFile from folder 'pending_process' but not delete
5. Move the source file from the folder 'pending_process' to a folder 'in_progress'
6. Business logic is already done that parses and does stuff with the flowFile data.
7. Upon completion of #6 I need move the original source file (not the flowFile) from the folder 'in_progress' to a folder 'completed'

**#7 is where I am having the issues for the final detection and moving of the source file from the in_progress to the completed folder**

How can I get NiFi to move upon completion of #6 the original source in the 'in_progress' folder to the final destination 'completed' folder?

Comment: what is behind #6? how you are triggering it? how it could talk to nifi?

Comment: @daggett GetFile would send the flowFile into #6 and the process will take about 2 hours to complete. Once it completes then I would want a way to tell NiFi to take that source file that was used on the GetFile to move it to a new location 'completed'

Comment: I am still looking for a solution to this. Google has not been my friend in finding a solution to this.

Comment: If business process working with files, then it's normal if on end of processing it'll create a file with `completed` marker. Like: `in_progress/filename.done`. then you could track it in nifi.